# Data extraction from text file by Matlab/Python

Tags: python, matlab, extract, text-files

I am very new to coding and need help. I have results of many iterations in a text file, as shown hereunder. I want to extract data of 2nd row and 2nd  column of each iteration.
For example, the below attached results, I need to extract 2nd cell value of step 1 of each iteration, which are 45.6803, 42.8168, 211.204 in 1st, 2nd and 3rd iternations, respectivily.

```
# Time-averaged data for fix msd1
# TimeStep Number-of-rows
# Row c_1[1] c_1[2] c_1[3] c_1[4]
1000 13
1 4.49974 45.6803 0.00953201 50.1896
2 0 0 0 0
3 0 0 0 0
4 0 0 0 0
5 0 0 0 0
6 0 0 0 0
7 0 0 0 0
8 0 0 0 0
9 0 0 0 0
10 0 0 0 0
11 0 0 0 0
12 0 0 0 0
13 7.44888 27.9179 0.00378638 35.3706
2000 13
1 12.2563 42.8168 0.00184897 55.0749
2 0 0 0 0
3 0 0 0 0
4 0 0 0 0
5 0 0 0 0
6 0 0 0 0
7 0 0 0 0
8 0 0 0 0
9 0 0 0 0
10 0 0 0 0
11 0 0 0 0
12 0 0 0 0
13 0.554336 46.7217 2.2856 49.5617
3000 13
1 28.5347 211.204 9.86051 249.6
2 0 0 0 0
3 0 0 0 0
4 0 0 0 0
5 0 0 0 0
6 0 0 0 0
7 0 0 0 0
8 0 0 0 0
9 0 0 0 0
10 0 0 0 0
11 0 0 0 0
12 0.147786 84800.5 6343.95 91144.6
13 1.68952 931.212 2.37075 935.272
4000 13
1 37.5247 72.2563 8.61142 118.392
2 0 0 0 0
3 0 0 0 0
4 0 0 0 0
5 0 0 0 0
6 0 0 0 0
7 0 0 0 0
8 0 0 0 0
9 0 0 0 0
10 0 0 0 0
11 125.807 85126.6 5835.21 91087.6
12 92.8723 84771.7 6814.61 91679.2
13 5.86643 270.801 14.6892 291.356
5000 13
1 12.351 573.413 5.7357 591.499
2 1269.98 85017.3 816.385 87103.7
3 0 0 0 0
4 0 0 0 0
5 0 0 0 0
6 0 0 0 0
7 0 0 0 0
8 0 0 0 0
9 0 0 0 0
10 0 0 0 0
11 0.20919 85155.3 6062.01 91217.6
12 3.97979 84619.3 6717.17 91340.5
13 0.858492 825.117 21.973 847.949
```

Comment: In python, you need to open the file (best with a context manager), then you can iterate over its lines with `read_lines()`. Finally you can split each line on spaces and check if the first element matches "1". If so, you're desired output would be in the third element (remember lists are zero-indexed, so the indices you're interested in are 0 and 2). You should be able to Google any of these steps easily or ask your favorite LLM like chat gpt.